# How can I show that $ \int_{\Gamma_1}F\cdot dr-\int_{\Gamma_2}F\cdot dr=2k\pi $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $F:{\Bbb R}^2\to {\Bbb R}^2$ be such that
>   $$
> F(x,y)=\left(-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right).
> $$
>   Suppose we have to one-to-one $C^1$ curves: $\gamma_j:[0,1]\to{\Bbb R}^2$, such that
>   $$
> \gamma_j(0)=p, \ \ \gamma_j(1)=q, \quad j=1,2,
> $$
>   for some $p,q\in{\Bbb R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Assume furthermore that $\gamma_j(t)\not=(0,0)$ and $\gamma_j'(t)\not= 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, and $\gamma_1((0,1))\cap\gamma_2((0,1))=\emptyset$. Show that
>   $$
> \int_{\Gamma_1}F\cdot dr-\int_{\Gamma_2}F\cdot dr=2k\pi
> $$
>   where $k=0,1,-1$, and $\Gamma_j=\gamma_j([0,1])$.

---

When $p=(1,0)$, $q=(-1,0)$, let $\Gamma_1$ be the upper semi-circle and $\Gamma_2$ the lower one. Then one can show explicitly that $k=\pm 1$.How can one generalize this case?

**Some thoughts**:

- I think the result depends on whether $(0,0)$ is inside the closed curve $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ or not, which would give $k$ is zero or nonzero.
- A quick calculation renders that
  $$
  F=\nabla f
  $$
  where $f(x,y)=\arctan(y/x)$ when $x\not=0$. But this is not always true for ${\Bbb R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.
- Geometrically, $F$ is the unit outer normal on the unit circle. But I don't see how this might be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly,
$$
\int_{\Gamma_1}F\cdot dr-\int_{\Gamma_2}F\cdot dr=\int_{\gamma}\frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2},
$$
where $\gamma=\Gamma_1-\Gamma_2$, meaning $\gamma$ is the union of the two curves, with the second in the opposite direction, and hence $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve. But
$$
\int_{\gamma}\frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}=\mathrm{Im}\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z},
$$
where $z=x+\mathrm{i}y$. Now
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z},
$$
is the the index of $\gamma$ around $z=0$, or $\mathrm{Ind}_\gamma(0)$. If $0$ is not in the interior of $\gamma$, then $\mathrm{Ind}_\gamma(0)=0$. Otherwise it is equal to 1 or -1 depending on the orientation of $\gamma$.